# react-native-fbsdk - Getting error : Execution failed for task 'app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' after set-up

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am having a problem when installing react-native-fbsdk for Android. I install it, link it, so far so good; but when I make the necessary changes to the MainApplication.java, MainActivity.java, strings.xml and AndroidManifest.xml files, I get the following error when trying to run my project :

```
Execution failed for task 'app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
```

When no changes are made to the files, the app runs..
Does anyone know where my problem is ?
(I already tried react-native upgrade and it only erases the changes made to the different files)

Edit: 
Here is my build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
}
```

}

And I haven't made any changes to the rest of the project yet

Comment: Share code if you need help

Comment: Please post both your Java files and `build.gradle`

Comment: Also, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Hello man did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work yesterday, it was a mistake I made during the configuration of the package, you have to install it, then link it with the command "react-native link" BEFORE you start doing changes to the various files, then it works very well !